# SQL UPDATE column with self referenced id from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to update the `ParentId` of each row that is not null

With the `Id` from the row that has a `TemplateId` Matching ParentId

| Id | ParentId | TemplateID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | NULL | 86 |
| 1002 | 86 | 41 |
| 1003 | 43 | 44 |
| 1004 | NULL | 43 |
| 1005 | 44 | 73 |

Desired results:

| Id | ParentId | TemplateID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | NULL | 86 |
| 1002 | 1001 | 41 |
| 1003 | 1004 | 44 |
| 1004 | NULL | 43 |
| 1005 | 1003 | 73 |

The way I am doing it seems extremely convoluted. Is there a simpler way?

```
  UPDATE
    [dbo].[tbl]
  SET
    [ParentID] = [z].[ItemID]
  FROM
    [dbo].[tbl]
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      [x].[ParentID]
    FROM
      [dbo].[tbl]
    JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        [ParentID]
      FROM
        [dbo].[tbl]
      WHERE
        [ParentID] > 0
    ) [x]
    ON
      [dbo].[tbl].[TemplateID] = [x].[ParentID]
  ) [z]
  ON
    [dbo].[tbl].[ParentID] = [z].[ParentID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should gives you what you want. Self Join with `ParentID` = `TemplateID`

---

```
UPDATE t1
SET    ParentID = t2.ItemID
FROM   tbl t1
       INNER JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.ParentID = t2.TemplateID
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dfd74b7fdd2c80c1ea825431a9c08a22)